# Why the csv output is not identical to the original in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I'm opening a data file csv1.txt (in CSV format) at a Windows OS. When you open it in Windows notepad. it's like:

```
john|mary|joe34|25|332|21|4321|42|25
```

I use these codes in Jupyter Notebook to do the `read_csv` and `to_csv` in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csv1.txt', header=None)
df.to_csv('csv2.txt', header=False, index=False)
```

Then when I open csv2.txt, it looks like this:

```
john|mary|joe
34|25|3
32|21|43
21|42|25
```

**Is there a way to make csv2.txt identical to csv1.txt?**

Comment: Could you show me how to do it? Thanks! @jezrael

Comment: hmmm, is possible create sample data and give link in google docs, dropbox, wetransfer or similar? Because I think input data format is different

Answer (score 0):

You should probably provide the relevant `line_terminator` to `to_csv` e.g. assuming you're reading a unix-style CSV on Windows the input probably gets handled by universal newlines, then on writing Pandas uses `os.linesep` which is a "full" windows-style linebreak rather than a unix-style `'\n'`. Something along those lines.

That aside, providing relevant contextual environment is generally helpful to get answers, "When you open it, it's like:" when the reader has no idea what your OS is, what you mean by "open it", what the actual (raw) contents of the file is, etc...

Comment: I'd go with checking out the first paragraph then, notepad has historically had pretty bad support for unix-style (newline-terminated) files which would explain why your source is displayed as a single-line in notepad.

Comment: Is there a way to add more codes in to_csv to make it looks identical to csv1.txt? a single-line? @Masklinn

Comment: @xtronaltic as I said, use the `line_terminator` parameter, that overides the "end of line" character used by default.  You may want to check what the original uses (with a hex editor or something) but it's probably the newline character `"\n"`

Comment: You right bro, df.to_csv('csv2.txt', header=False, index=False,line_terminator='\n') fixed it